# How does UEFI do task scheduling

Tags: uefi

Since UEFI can have multiple drivers and applications run before the OS boots is there a scheduler present which allows multitasking of these programs?

Or is everything just sequential execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UEFI has a very simple scheduler based on a global timer, that schedules events according to their priority level and registration order. Execution is mostly sequential, as UEFI is designed to be executed on a single core within a single thread.

Check out "Events and task priority levels" and "Task Priority Level(TPL) Services" chapters of [UEFI DWG](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/UEFI-Driver-Writer's-Guide) to know more about event types and TPLs.